# How to move images faster using Gallery

Tags: android, gallery

I'm posting my files here:
When I run the program the images appear but when I slide them they tend to slide very slowly. How can I make it go faster? This is my xml file:

```
            <Gallery
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/gallery"
                android:isScrollContainer="true"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>




gallery.setSpacing(1);
        final GalleryImageAdapter galleryAdapter = new GalleryImageAdapter(this);
        gallery.setAdapter(galleryAdapter);

        gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                 SelectedImage.setImageResource(galleryAdapter.mImageIds[position]);
            }
        });
    }

@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);
        i.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
        i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(200, 200));
        i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        return i;
    }
    public Integer[] mImageIds={
            R.drawable.a,
            R.drawable.b,
            R.drawable.c
    };
```

Comment: rest of  the code

@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

        ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);
        i.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
        i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(200, 200));
        i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        return i;
    }
    public Integer[] mImageIds={
            R.drawable.a,
            R.drawable.b,
            R.drawable.c
    };

Comment: final GalleryImageAdapter galleryAdapter = new GalleryImageAdapter(this);
        gallery.setAdapter(galleryAdapter);

        gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                SelectedImage.setImageResource(galleryAdapter.mImageIds[position]);
            }
        });
    }

Comment: Would you please edit the question to add the rest of the code?  Unfortunately, that much code pasted into a comment is not readable.

Comment: edited the code.. sorry for the inconvenience